# Bloom Filters - Implementing Hash Functions

Tags: hash, bloom-filter

fairly simple question here. Ok, so I understand the basics of using a bloom filter to check whether a member is **not** part of a set, the way that the bit array works, the way that the # of hash functions to use and etc. are calculated, but what I don't get in the implementation is how you are mapping characters to bytes.

For example, lets say that I hash the input 1 and the output is 8, and then I set bit8 to 1, to indicate that the member is part of the set. How would you do this with a functions like FNV or Jenkins', or really any hash function that returns characters along with integers. If this is a stupid question don't hesitate to tell me, I just am not getting the implementation of some of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Strings are array of characters(char datatype) and chars are either 16bit or 8 bit depending if the language is using utf or ascii. so in psuedo code it would look something like this:

```
    // ord() means ordinal or you could use typecasting.

    var 
     str: string;
     b:byte;
    str = "zoom" 
    b = (byte)str[4]; //delphi i would use b = ord(str[4]);
                   // now b contains the number for the letter m
```

Strings are just arrays and you may use them as so. in java you would just use String.IndextoByte or something similar.

I've written a tutorial on Bloom Filters, If you are interested
http://techeffigy.wordpress.com/2014/06/05/bloom-filter-tutorial